# Calling other methods/variables inside a UDF method in Spark SQL DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, udf

I have a Spark SQL DF, in which i am trying to call one UDF [ which i created using Spark SQL `udf`.

```
val udfName = udf(somemethodName)
val newDF = df.withColumn("columnnew", udfName(col("anotherDFColumn"))
```

I'm trying to use another DF stored as a `val` inside the somemethodName, but the DF is coming as null.

This is happening only when i use where clause in the `newDF`.

Am i missing something?Is it not possible to use another variable / method inside UDF method?

Or do i have to do something with broadcast? Currently i am running this on local, not in the cluster though.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it not possible to use another variable / method inside UDF method

It *is* possible if and only if that variable / method can be **serialized** - a UDF is a closure that must be serialized and distributed to executors.

A **Dataframe** cannot be serialized (it's a pointer to other distributed data, so there's no logical way to serialize it without collecting it into Driver memory), therefore appears as `null` when you try to use the UDF.

You're probably going to need to `join` the two dataframes on some key, and then use a UDF (or a standard transformation) that takes columns from the joined Dataframe.

Comment: In fact `Dataset` / `Dataframe` can be serialized. Just cannot be used in the UDF closure.

Comment: @Tzach Zohar: There is no common key between the dataframes, so i cannot join, the other dataframe is just a lookup file., having some ranges values like 0 to 60 etc.. how can i use the lookup inside the UDF? i hope i can read the lookup file inside udf method, but for each and every record i need to load the entire file...

Comment: @LostInOverflow: Can i use the List, which is defined outside the UDF method name? I`m planning to read the range from the file and create a list, then use the list inside UDF method.. will it work?

Comment: Yes, you can use any non-distributed data structure.